# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fototekn_digi.ln_filter' doesn't exist

Tags: magento-1.9

Why I am getting the following MySQL error?

```
SQLSTATE[42S02 Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fototekn_digi.ln_filter' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ln_filter` AS `main_table` WHERE (attribute_code = 'price')";
0 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
1 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
2 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
3 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
4 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(*)...', Array)
5 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
6 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(225): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
7 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/local/EM/LayeredNavigation/Block/Adminhtml/Filter/Grid.php(20): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
8 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): EM_LayeredNavigation_Block_Adminhtml_Filter_Grid->_prepareCollection()
9 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
10 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(929): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
11 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(648): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
12 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(592): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
13 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
14 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
15 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/chroot/home/fo...')
16 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
17 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
18 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
19 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
20 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(930): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
21 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
22 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(930): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
23 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(648): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
24 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(592): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
25 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
26 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/chroot/home/fo...')
27 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
28 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
29 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
30 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(930): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
31 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
32 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
33 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/local/EM/LayeredNavigation/controllers/Adminhtml/FilterController.php(12): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
34 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): EM_LayeredNavigation_Adminhtml_FilterController->indexAction()
35 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
36 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
37 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
38 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
39 /chroot/home/fototekn/fototeknoloji.com/html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
40 {main}";s:3:"url";s:80:"/index.php/layernav/adminhtml_filter/index/key/1f03428d4c76b6a6754acb3d90df4119/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you're getting the error because the table `fototekn_digi.ln_filter` does not exist.

The original query that caused that error was:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `ln_filter` AS `main_table` WHERE (attribute_code = 'price')";
```

It would seem that somehow the `ln_filter` table is resolving to a full name of `fototekn_digi.ln_filter`, and that no table exists by that fully qualified name.

If you would like more help with this issue, I would suggest providing some or all of the following:

- What steps have you tried to resolve the error or deduce its origin?
- How is this error being produced? What code is causing the error?
- Do you expect a table named `ln_filter` to exist?

Comment: hi,
we in_filt name thanks to troubleshoot I get the error changed the variable name @Cory Klein :) good work.

Comment: @serhatocal Thank you. If you appreciate the effort made to write this answer, you are welcome to upvote it by clicking the up arrow.